# Recieve an error " 'File' object has no attribute 'dat_fmt' ", while trying to read a .spc file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python, and am trying to read a file as follows:

```py
from pyspectra.readers.read_spc import read_spc
spc=read_spc('.../12.spc')
```

I get:

```
File type 0x7 not supported yet. Please add issue. #this function is specifically created to read this type of files 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../python_file.py", line 2, in <module>
    spc=read_spc('.../12.spc')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspectra/readers/read_spc.py", line 10, in read_spc
    if f.dat_fmt.endswith('-xy'):
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'dat_fmt'. Did you mean: 'data_txt'?
```

I've tried multiple libraries for reading .scp files: spectrochempy, specio, and pyspectra. The closest I've actually gotten to reading a file is with the last option.
I'm using Ubuntu, and have given all the possible permissions to the file in question.
If you, by any chance, know another way to read .scp files, or know how to fix this error, please share. :(

Comment: I would imagine the error is due to `File type 0x7 not supported yet`.